# NGROK not working for for WAN or outside local network

Tags: ngrok

Most of the time when I try to connect my ngrok with a webhook for testing purposes or for accessing my local setup outside my local area network or from a wide area network it does not let me connect displaying ngrok tunnel not found. It's been a while since I'm searching for a solution over the internet. The machine I'm working on is MacBook Pro 2020.

Answer (score 0):

***This solution only tested on the MacBook Pro and Its Temporary***

You would have noticed when you create a tunnel from your terminal it's being displayed in your ngrok dashboard which you can access by login into your ngrok account. For this behaviour of ngrok is asymptotic sometimes on the same network tunnel is accessible globally over internet and sometimes ngrok tunnel was accessible only from local area network. Some of the possible fixes for tunnel not found I tried are

1. Switch your network It may be possible your ISP start blocking ngrok and didn't allow it ot be accessible from outside your local area network.
2. Uninstall Your ngrok and reinstall it. (I use `brew install ngrok` to install it and `brew uninstall ngrok` for removing it).
3. Try restarting your machine.
4. Try changing the IP address assigned to you by your router

*These are some possible fixes I tried and they worked for me more solutions are welcome*